# Python 3.5 broken my apt

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.5, apt, dpkg

Ubuntu 16.04
When I restore my system from backup after system fault, I got broken apt.

When I trying use apt, for example:

```
$ sudo apt install pyroom 
Setting up python3 (3.5.1-3) ...
running python rtupdate hooks for python3.5...
dpkg-query: package 'rhythmbox-plugins' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of rhythmbox-plugins
error running python rtupdate hook rhythmbox-plugins
dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 4
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I check my apt list:

`$ apt list python3.5`

`Listing... Done`

`python3.5/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]`

When I try reconfigure, I got errors:

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up python3 (3.5.1-3) ...
running python rtupdate hooks for python3.5...
dpkg-query: package 'rhythmbox-plugins' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of rhythmbox-plugins
error running python rtupdate hook rhythmbox-plugins
dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 4
dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gnome-menus:
 gnome-menus depends on python3:any (>= 3.1~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-menus (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3
 gnome-menus
```

What can I do to fix that?

Comment: did you try to `$ sudo apt install rhythmbox-plugins`?

Comment: @hiroprotagonist It doesn't help. Errors were encountered while processing: python3, rhythmbox-plugins

Comment: `pyroom` installs nicely on my `xenial`. maybe this question is a better fit for [ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)... (does `sudo apt install -f` help?)

Comment: @hiroprotagonist I investigated that currently different package dependencies: apt list python3.5 = 3.5.2-2, but broken dependency: 3.5.1-3. I'll try to delete packages depend from 3.5.1 and check it. Currently issue unsuccessful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent several days to find solution.
I investigated that currently different package dependencies:

`$ apt list python3.5
Listing... Done
python3.5/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]`

but broken dependency: `Python 3.5.1-3`.

I deleted packages depended from `Python 3.5.1` and installed them again.

Then run:

`$ sudo dpkg --configure -a`

I got successful result.

Comment: Could you please explain how you figured there were broken dependencies with Python 3.5.1-3?  I did "apt-cache rdepends python3.5.1" but nothing shows up!

Comment: Same exact nonworking "solution" that seems to be all over SO. Done this fifteen times already. It doesn't help anything.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by removing the .rtupdate files in the directory /usr/share/python3/runtime.d and reinstalling python3.

Comment: I don't know how I ended up with my system broken like this; I think I ran `apt-get upgrade` while `unattended-upgrades` was working away, and it left me in a state where I could not use apt or dpkg because almost any command would end in "Exception: cannot get content of ...". This is the only solution that worked: `rm /usr/share/python3/runtime.d/*.rtupdate; dpkg --configure -a; apt-get install --reinstall --fix-broken`